# IONIC1 Show Gallery Images

Tags: angularjs, ionic-v1

I am using [cordova-plugin-photo-library](https://github.com/terikon/cordova-plugin-photo-library/) to show gallery images in my app. I have used their photoLibrary.getLibrary() method to get the image. That methods returns two type of url:-

```
photoURL(ex:- cdvphotolibrary://photo?photoId=ADB24867-0CCB-4207-923A-DC9D44233434%2FL0%2F001)

filePath(Ex:- /var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0652.JPG)
```

I have tried to show image using either of those path. I am able to show the images using filePath but could not show the image using photoURL. All images does not return filePath. **Could anyone can help me to show images using photoURL?**

As per their doc we can show directly using photoURL all we have to use imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(). I have tried but it's not working.